# Counterclockwise eclipse error on 1st command

Tags: eclipse, clojure, jvm, read-eval-print-loop, counterclockwise

I began looking into lisp recently, and installed Counterclockwise with Eclipse.
Then, hating the fact that the 1.2 version is built in, I manually linked the 1.3 library into it (not very difficult honestly)...
Then I noticed that each time I run a *new* REPL session, the first command always makes a bunch of errors show up,  with no effect on the session itself. At the same time, all following commands work fine.

It's only a minor annoyance, but still pretty unnerving. I've tested it with 1.2 (built in version) by reversing the changes I made, but that didn't help.

Here is the long list of Eclipse Console output (there are 6 more, but eclipse didn't write them, I might go and try to simulate the same inside of a cmd, but please tell me if it's necessary 1st)

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl$handle_response.invoke(nrepl.clj:265)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl$message_dispatch$fn__181.invoke(nrepl.clj:305)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.core$refer.doInvoke(core.clj:3775)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5252)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:258)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl$handle_request.invoke(nrepl.clj:240)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:409)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl$message_dispatch$fn__181$fn__184.invoke(nrepl.clj:302)
    ... 6 more
```

**Edit**: There's a chance this may be linked to namespaces

```
(ns Something)
```

even if nothing in the file is actually used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post an issue on the google code page here: http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/issues/list
and send email to the google group here: http://groups.google.com/group/clojuredev-users?pli=1

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a namespace name problem.

I can generate this error easily on ccw 0.5.0.STABLE002:
1) I create a new project using wizard: File->New->Project..->Clojure Project
2) I create file core.clj in src folder
3) I change namespace name.

After running REPL for the file core.clj I get the same exception.

I found this problem after creating project with lein with the name containing HYPEN "-"

When I use project name with hypen then package names are created with underscore "_". After calling lein eclipse (:dev-dependencies [[lein-eclipse "1.0.0"]]) project clould be imported properly to eclipse. REPL works perfect. But it is not possible to compile project with lein. For this hypen in namespace name have to be changed to underscore. After the change compilation with lein became possible but REPL in ccw started generating not well described exception enclosed by you in the question.

My advice after this experience do not use hypens or underscores in project names.